# MongoDB timeout connection with .net core

Tags: c#, mongodb, docker

i have this environment

- dot net core
- docker
- mongoDB
- on the machine there is MacAfee anti various

when i ran my application it gave me timeout error, even when i ran it directly or when i use docker composer file. i tried several solutions to overcome the error, such as
- Add connection string to "?connect=replicaSet"
- change port as the following (i return it back to 27017 to try other solutions)

> services:
> catalogdb:
> container_name: catalogdb
> restart: always
> volumes:
> - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site:/data/db
> ports:
> - "27018:27017"

```
    - Check firewall settings.
```

[image: open port]

This is the error I still getting it , even when I tried all above solutions :

> System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a
> server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
> LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
> } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode
> : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers :
> [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint :
> "Unspecified/localhost:27017" }", EndPoint:
> "Unspecified/localhost:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State:
> "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown",
> HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An
> exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.  --->
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested
> address    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint
> remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectAsync(EndPoint remoteEP)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.ConnectAsync(Socket
> socket, EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint
> endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnectionAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp:
> "2020-11-18T10:13:02.8975142Z", LastUpdateTimestamp:
> "2020-11-18T10:13:02.8975144Z" }] }.

**still getting timeout error. any help?**

---

### update

attached the docker containers screenshot
[image]

Comment: That error message isn't super useful, it's just the standard timeout response - the issue is in your connection between the dotnet code and the mongo database. You said 'docker' above - are you running your dotnet app and mongodb in separate containers on the same host? If you're doing that, you probably want to add them to a docker network and have them address each other by container name.

Comment: i have attached how the containers in docker.

Comment: You'll want to add your containers to a new shared [Docker Network](https://docs.docker.com/network/) - they can then address each other by the name of the container, so your connection string in the api would become "mongodb://catalogdb:27017".

Answer (score 1):

In .net core project, local application *secrets.json* file add below two entries

**secrets.json**

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings:MongoDb-Local": "mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017",
  "ConnectionStrings:MongoDb-Container": "mongodb://admin:password@mongodb.container:27017"
}
```

In .net core project where you are reading mongodb configuration, check whether the calling application is running in container (or) not? using .net environment variable *"DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER"*.

**Program.cs**

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

var isRunningInContainer = configuration.GetValue<bool>("DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER");

var connectionStr = isRunningInContainer ?
    configuration.GetConnectionString("MongoDb-Container") :
    configuration.GetConnectionString("MongoDb-Local");
```